# What's best way to improve the gang's safe house in Payday 2?

Tags: payday-2

I've been collecting continental coins for a while, and now it's time to spend them. I know the majority of the upgrades are just aesthetic, but do any of them affect the gameplay in some way?

Comment: You may want to edit this to ask "what do the upgrades do" otherwise asking "what's best" will get this close for being opinion based

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some additional benefits that are not noted here. For one, you can gamble your on-hand cash in the "casino" area after upgrading it a few times -- at max upgrades it should have a few machines.

Additionally, when it comes to safe house invasions, it may be more beneficial to you have more furniture lying around as a result from upgrading specific parts of your safe house because remember, the more furniture, the more cover you have when dealing with these kinds of missions.

Comment: I thought about including the furniture part into my answer, but decided that it wasn't affecting the game play enough.  I did consider though.  It certainly does change the game play for these missions, but I was thinking that game play meant more like shaving time off escapes by having a quicker van through having an upgraded garage - stuff like that.

Comment: Making money is gameplay too, thats kind of the point of the game. I like to think of adding new furniture as "preplanning"

Answer (score 6):

From what I've found, all safehouse upgrades do not impact gameplay in any way.  They are cosmetic only.

[One Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/paydaytheheist/comments/5p3kzd/is_it_better_to_spend_continental_coins_on/) stated:

> Safehouse is only aesthetic, I believe if you upgrade the garage you get new van colour options but other than that there's no real benefit.

Multiple pages stated that the garage gives you a new van color, but again, this is cosmetic only.

A [Steam Post](https://steamcommunity.com/app/218620/discussions/8/340412122413164326/) also seems to agree with Reddit.

Comment: Yeah, I've got all the upgrades, only thing you'll see to affect in-mission  is a choice of two more schemes for the van's paint. Inside the safehouse, the shooting range allows you to compare guns, and there's a training range you can race to complete. Minigame stuff though really, nothing to change gameplay.